# How to define variable "Rainbow" curve colors?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color

Firstly, I'm not asking about blending a color gradient on a curve.

I would like to make the curve color uniform on all its lenght instead, but the color should change dynamically while we slide a Manipulate slider.  Secondly, the colors should be from the "Rainbow" color palette, going from "deep red" when the *T* parameter (*temperature*) takes its lowest value, and the color should gradually change to the "deep purple" color when *T* takes its highest value.

Here's a MWE example that shows the idea, using a simple variation of color linked to the temperature (I hope the idea is clear) :

```
color[T_] := RGBColor[1 (10 - T)/(10 - 1), 0, 1 (T - 1)/(10 - 1)]

Planck[T_, colorparameter_] := Plot[
    (1/lambda)^5/(Exp[100/(T lambda)] - 1),
    {lambda, 0, 10},
    PlotPoints -> Automatic,
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, colorparameter],
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
]

Manipulate[
    Show[
        {Planck[T, color[T]]},
        PlotRange -> All,
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        Frame -> True,
        ImageSize -> {400, 400}
    ],
{
    {T, 5, Style["T ( K ) ", 10]},
    1, 10, 0.1,
    ImageSize -> Large
},
ControlPlacement -> Bottom
]
```

Currently, the function `color[T_]` is not the proper one.  It should be changed to something that uses the "Rainbow" palette.

Comment: Does something like `Manipulate[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}, a]], {a, 0, 1}]` work for you?

Comment: What J.M. said, although for your situation it would be something like `color[T_] = ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][(T - 1)/9];` since `T` goes from 1 to 10.

Comment: @C.E., I'm getting an error message : `ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}] is not a graphics directive.`.  I believe that "Reverse" is unknown (not sure).

Comment: The function `color[T_] = ColorData["Rainbow"][(T - 1)/9];`is working, but the colors are inverted.

Comment: Why not use a handy feature of `ColorData[]` to accept domains? `Manipulate[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {10, 1}}, a]], {a, 1, 10}]`.

Comment: @J.M., I'm not sure this is working with MMA v7.  Currently, the code doesn't work.

Comment: What does `ColorData[{"Rainbow", {10, 1}}, 5]` return for you, then?

Comment: @J.M., it gives `is not a known entity, class, or tag for "ColorData. Use ColorData[]`

Comment: OK, then yes, it's not yet supported in your version. Use `Rescale[]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Clear[color];
color = ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}];

Planck[T_, colorparameter_] := 
 Plot[(1/lambda)^5/(Exp[100/(T lambda)] - 1), {lambda, 0, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, colorparameter], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]

max = 10;

Manipulate[
 Show[{Planck[T, color[T/max]]}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> {400, 400}], {{T, 5, Style["T ( K ) ", max]}, 1, max, 
  0.1, ImageSize -> Large}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: This is working, except that the colors are inverted.  I need the deep purple to be associated to the highest value of T, while deep red is associated to the lowest value of T.

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Well, when I slide the slider to 10, the curve turns red.  At T = 1, the curve is bluish (or "deep purple").  It should be the reverse (red is associated to the lowest temperature).

Comment: start a fresh new notebook and copy the code above ... delete you color function

Comment: The option `"Reverse"`doesn't seem to be recognized by MMA version 7.  Is there another way to reverse the Rainbow ?

Comment: Doh !  Just use this `color[(max - T)/max]`, instead of "Reverse" !  Now it's working.  I'll adjust all this tomorrow.  Now it's time to go to bed !  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
tRange = {1, 10};
col[x_, range_] := ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - Rescale[x, range]]

Manipulate[Plot[x^-5/(Exp[100/(t x)] - 1), {x, 0, 10}, 
                PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, col[t, tRange]]], 
          {{t, 5, Style["T (K) ", Last@tRange]}, Sequence @@ tRange, 0.1}]
```

[image]